# VS Code: convert accented characters to HTML automatically

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

Editing an HTML file in Visual Studio Code, when I type `école` I want it to be replaced with `&eacute;cole` without doing any other action. What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'll offer this as a solution but you would have to do a lot of work to set it up first.  But since no one else has offered anything, how about snippets:

```
"Print e-acute": {
    "prefix": "é",
    "body": [
        "&eacute;"
    ],
    "description": "replace é with &eacute;"
}
```

I've tested it and it works.  But there are a lot of html character entity references to input.  If you were really good you could make a program to grab the list and create the snippets for entities 161-255 automatically.  I'm surprised there isn't an extension already available for this.

Comment: Even if I have to make 15 of these, it remains the fastest and most user friendly implementation. Thank you very much @Mark.

Comment: Is this really the only way right now? Visual Studio has a plugin for that. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GordonBreuer.UnicodeConverter