# In VS code, can I disable the auto converting from `.` to `->` of C++ pointer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

For some reason, I want to disable the auto converting from `.` to `->` of C++ pointer.

Is it possible?

Thank you.

(Updated)

The reason is that, I'm using a special compiler, and the compiler uses `.` instead of `->` for pointers.

[image]

Comment: what do you plan to put after the '.'

Comment: Hi @pm100, I just want `node.globalNext`

Comment: if node is a pointer then thats not valid code, thats why vs is changing it

Comment: Don’t use autocomplete and it won’t change your .

Comment: Will [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200255/vs-code-convert-accented-characters-to-html-automatically) helpful? or [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GordonBreuer.UnicodeConverter&ssr=false)?

Comment: @pm100 I know. But I'm not actually using C++. I'm using a language which is very similar to C++ so I associate the language to C++ syntax. But in the language, pointer uses `.` instead of `->`

Comment: @Taekahn Thank you, but I want autocomplete to show the class's members/functions etc.

Comment: @Kalana Thank you. Maybe I misunderstood, but I think the use case is different

Comment: turn off the c++ extension

Comment: “I’m not actually using c++” then why would you tag the question c++? You literally even mention it being c++ in the title and in the body.

Comment: @Taekahn Sorry for the confusing title. I'm doing everything exactly the same with c++. The only difference is `.` and `->` for pointer

Comment: Maybe my explanation about language is wrong. I'm using a special compiler to compile C++ files

Comment: If VScode doesn't handle your language correctly, submit a *Feature Request* on [Issues · microsoft/vscode - GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues)

Comment: @EricSun dropping `operator->` is a fairly major change. How do you deal with smart pointers? If the answer is "I don't use them" then you aren't writing anything *close* to C++

Comment: Is the C++ extension autocorrection for VS Code closed source? The source seems to be here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools Anybody know, where to configure the autocorrect settings?

Comment: I'm only using `new` and `delete` so far. Maybe I would use `unique_ptr` or other things some day

Comment: Yes, I've checked `vscode-cpptools` repo, but didn't find the setting either